# R function returning false values when taking mean from multiple .csv files

Tags: r, function, csv

I am trying to take out the mean from multiple .csv files which have null values. The function is:

```
pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {

#getting and setting wd
currentwd<-getwd()
if (grep(pattern = directory,x = currentwd)) {}
else {setwd(paste("./",directory,"/",sep=""))}

#declaring objects
x<-1    
poll<-pollutant
meandata<-c()

#Looping through the files
for (i in id){    

    #Appending leading zero's to the file names
    j<-c()
    if (i<10) {j<-paste("00",i,".csv",sep="")}
    else if (i>=10 & i<100) {j<-paste("0",i,".csv",sep="")}
    else {}

    #Adding means of pollutant in meandata
    temp <- read.csv(file = j, head = TRUE, sep = ",")
    meandata[x] <- mean(temp[,poll], na.rm = TRUE)
    x<-x+1
}

#rounding and displaying values
round(mean(meandata),3)}
```

The files have leading zeros (eg: 001.csv, 010.csv, 167.csv) so I've added an IF ELSE statement to append the zero's wherever necessary. They contain column vise data with pollutant name as the head.

When I run this for one .csv file, it gives the right output but if I to use this for multiple .csv files then it returns a wrong/false value.

Any help regarding where I'm going wrong would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try `sprintf("%03d.csv", 1:332)` in place of the if-else for creating the file names.  The best thing to do would be to run each line one by one to find out where the error occurs

Comment: I get the feeling you did not add `".csv"` for `i>=100`. Maybe you should add that to `else {}`?

Comment: Placing all needed `csv` files in a single directory (moving unnecessary files out) and looping over items in `list.files(pattern = "*.csv")` would likely simplify the work a lot.

Comment: I think taking out the mean twice and rounding the value is maybe causing the problem. I'll take both of your suggestions into consideration while rewriting the function on the weekend. @Molx, I forgot  to add that while posting but its there in the actual function. You have a good eye. Thank you for the suggestions everyone